# use UIGestureRecognizer to get video urls from the Table View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

My target is to list the videos from the library, and get the url on tapping each item.

I managed to get all the videos from the photo library and I set the textLabel to the url. However, when I tap the videos, all the videos NSLog out the url of the video which is in the final cell. How can I actually get the url of each video? I can't figure out what was the problem.

Here is some key lines of my `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }

    if (tableView.tag==0)
    {
        ALAsset *asset = [videoLibrary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        videoURL = [[asset defaultRepresentation] url];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        //here I am trying to print out the urls
        NSLog(@"-------- the url is: ---------");
        NSLog(@"%@", videoURL);
        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@", indexPath.row+1, videoURL]];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
        //where the cells get the gesturerecognizer
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Show Resume"];
    }
    return cell;
```

And this is my handler method:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [super self];
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"clicked! I can get url: [%@] here!", videoURL);
    }
}
```

What was wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why are you not using didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Hi, you are actually right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease change your method `- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender` to :

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender.view;
        NSLog(@"clicked! I can get url: [%@] here!", cell.textLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, I see, you print out the text in the cell, but is there a way to print out the real url of the videos?

Comment: Yes, it is possible added NSMutableArray* videosUrls_;

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
add: 
[videosUrls_ addObject: videoURL];
and in - (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender:

NSIndexPath* path = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"clicked! I can get url: [%@] here!", [videosUrls_ objectAtIndex:path.row]);

Comment: NSMutableArray* videosUrls_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: this is very close to what I want! I have pushed the urls to an array now, but I'm struggling getting the index of the cells. the problem is this line: NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; I have declared the cell and the tableView in the header file so that both of the methods can access these instances. the final error now was "no visible @interface for UITableViewCell declares the selector 'indexPathForCell:'", how can I fix this? Sorry if the question is too dum, I am beginner. thanks a lot.

Comment: try:
NSIndexPath* path = [(UITableView*)cell.superview indexPathForCell:cell];

Comment: the path.row now is 10 all the time, so back to the original situation.

Comment: find the solution! using didSelectRowAtIndexPath as Bhargavi suggested, so that I can set index as [indexPath row] because - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath has all the instances and objects I wanted, then there will be no global/local instance problem. I'll take your answer as answer, because this is where I got my answer, thank you so much for your time!